# Transforming a big .json file into a table

Tags: python, html, json

I have a .json file with keys such as "URL", "text" (which is very long), "abstract", "author", "image" etc. I want to construct an HTML table in Python with all these values, except for the text. I tried it with json2html in these two ways (it worked only for very small examples):

```
import json
data_processed = json.loads('C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\myfile.json')
formatted_table = json2html.convert(json = data_processed)
```

But it throws the error:

```
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-b8f0fd5ea78d> in <module>
      1 import json
----> 2 data_processed = json.loads('C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\myfile.json')
      3 formatted_table = json2html.convert(json = data_processed)

~\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    346             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    347             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 348         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    349     if cls is None:
    350         cls = JSONDecoder

~\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    335 
    336         """
--> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338         end = _w(s, end).end()
    339         if end != len(s):

~\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

The other way was:

```
from json2html import *
input2 = {
        "name": "something",
        "description": "some description"
}
json2html.convert(json = input2)
```

But I don't know how to import my file instead of this dictionary.

Comment: You are trying to parse the filename as the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you meant to open the file first and then read it into `data_processed`.

```
with open("C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\myfile.json") as fp:
    data_processed = json.load(fp)
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Is it possible to delete the "text" column when generating the table? I knew it was possible with OpenJSON in SQL Server, but how does it work in Python?

Comment: To delete the column you can just delete the key text for all elements, by doing something like this ```for e in data_processed: del e['text']```